Why does the player gameObject continue moving in mid-air, despite no movement keys being pressed? (closed)
I'm making a 2D game in Unity where the player is able to jump and walk left or right. The player should be able to change directions while mid-air, but the problem is that they continue to move in the direction they were moving while jumping, despite no longer pressing the movement key.
Here's the movement script:
public float jumpHeight;

public float speed;

public Rigidbody2D rb;

private bool isGrounded;

public Transform feetPos;

public float checkRadius;

public LayerMask Ground;

private float jumpTimeCounter;

public float jumpTime;

private bool isJumping;

void Update()
{
    PausedThisFrame = false;

    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, Ground);

    if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        isJumping = true;
        jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpHeight;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping)
    {
        if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpHeight;
            jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        Debug.Log("A");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-1 * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        Debug.Log("D");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(1 * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}

I tried debugging the code to see if the script thinks the keys are being pressed but even the script knows that they aren't so i trully have no idea what's changing the velocity of the rigidbody.

Sorry, is the velocity changing or not? they continue to move in the direction they were moving while jumping makes it sound like the velocity isn't changing. But i trully have no idea what's changing the velocity of the rigidbody. makes it sound like it is.

i'm sorry, by that i meant that it's just moving in a direction.

That doesn't answer my question if the velocity is changing or not when the player releases control

a demonstration. i press space which makes the player jump. i press (not hold but press) the D key while they are still mid-air which makes the player go right. instead of the player stopping moving right after i release the D key, they continue moving in that direction untill they hit the ground.

so in other words their horizontal velocity does not change (and is the unexpected behavior) but their vertical velocity is allowed to continue changing due to gravity (and is expected). thank you for clarifying

The else part of your FixedUpdate() routine seems to be the problem.
The part
else
{
rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y);
}

only assign a copy of the velocity vector to itself. So, the values do not change.
Try this one instead of the else
if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) &&
    !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
    }

The input check is necessary to only set the x-velocity to zero, when no key is pressed ;)

This changes nothing unfortunartely. Even if i remove the "else" part, it's still the same.

@Vota There's no else in what this answer is suggesting you do. Did you read this answer carefully?

thanks @Ruzihm, i didn't notice that levarris swapped out the else for an if. sorry that i missed that, this made it work.

else {
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
}

Set the horizontal velocity to zero

This changes nothing unfortunartely. Even if i remove the "else" part, it's still the same.

This looks like it will result in the character not being able to move to the left since it will override any changes done by the if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) block

You are adding to the rb.velocity.x with
rb.velocity = new Vector2(1 * speed, rb.velocity.y);

but you are never decreasing it... In the statement below you are basicly telling it that velocity = velocity.
Try replacing
else
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y);
}

with something like
else
{
    rb.velocity = new  Vector2(Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0, Time.deltaTime * rb.drag), rb.velocity.y);
}


This changes nothing unfortunartely. Even if i remove the "else" part, it's still the same.

What is your rigidbody "Linear Drag" set to?

The statement Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0, Time.deltaTime * rb.drag); doesn't change anything. - did you forget to assign the result of to a variable?

@azelito my rigidbody linear drag is set to 0

The example above decreases the movement over time by the amount of Linear Drag. If your Linear Drag is 0 the code does nothing... :)

The example else {     Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0, Time.deltaTime * rb.drag); } doesn't do anything with linear drag

You are completely right. I forgot to assign the value to anything at all, duh. Serves me right for not trying my example out before posting.
